# Match multiple groups of curly brackets, but get separate groups within

Tags: javascript, regex

I have got the following string below. I need to first of all match each set of curly braces, but also the key as well. This is the string:

> Starting watch tasks... {less: LESS} {javascript: JavaScript} {images: Images} {files Files}

So as an example, I would need to regex to match my string in a similar fashion to this:

```
[
    'less': '{less: LESS}',
    'javascript': '{javascript: JavaScript}',
    'images': '{images: Images}',
    'files': '{files: Files}',
]
```

So the text to the right of the `:` is simply a text string which could be anything, anything to the left of `:` is the key. And `{}` is a group.

Comment: Fix whatever's sending you that broken input to send you proper JSON instead, and then you can parse the JSON

Comment: @CertainPerformance see updated post, think I ordered it a bit wrong and you misunderstood.

Comment: I see what you're trying to do, it's just a very X/Y problem, *and* it doesn't look like you've tried anything yourself yet either

Comment: I have attempted and failed, didn't see the point in posted my attempts which are very likely COMPLETELY wrong.

Comment: Can you change how the original string is created? Or is that bad format set in stone?

Comment: That can be changed, I just need to basically have groups, with a key and value. @ChrisG

Comment: So how about sending something like `{ "less": "LESS", "javascript": "JavaScript" }`, that's valid JSON that can easily be composed on the server and parsed on the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
const s = `Starting watch tasks... {less: LESS} {javascript: JavaScript} {images: Images} {files Files}`;
const regExp = /{([^:]+):[^}]+}/g;

let m;
let result = {};
while ((m = regExp.exec(s))) {
  result[m[1]] = m[0];
}

console.log(result);
```